# PyODConverter Fails for Files with Japanese name

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, libreoffice, pyuno

I am unable to use `PyODConverter` to convert files to other formats, if the files are having filename in Japanese or Chinese.

**Break point:**

```
document = self.desktop.loadComponentFromURL(inputUrl, "_blank", 0, self._toProperties(loadProperties))
```

This fails incase if the file-name is in Japanese works great for English.

**Steps to regenerate the issue:**

1. file path : `/home/vivek/workspace/qwiktrans/code//media/multiuploader/201401業務委託契約書QUIKSILVER様_3_55.doc`
2. generate inputURL using `inputUrl = self._toFileUrl(inputFile)`
3. The input URL:

   `/home/vivek/workspace/qwiktrans/code//media/multiuploader/201401%E6%A5%AD%E5%8B%99%E5%A7%94%E8%A8%97%E5%A5%91%E7%B4%84%E6%9B%B8QUIKSILVER%E6%A7%98_3_55.doc`

   4) when you will apply this inputUrl it will Fail.

   `document = self.desktop.loadComponentFromURL(inputUrl, "_blank", 0, self._toProperties(loadProperties))`

**Error message:**

> com.sun.star.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported URL file:///home/vivek/workspace/qwiktrans/code/media/multiuploader/201401%E6%A5%AD%E5%8B%99%E5%A7%94%E8%A8%97%E5%A5%91%E7%B4%84%E6%9B%B8QUIKSILVER%E6%A7%98_3_55.doc: ""

Please suggest

Note: I am using Django1.4 with python2.7 on ubuntu12.04 having libreoffice and unoconv 0.6

Comment: gibberish ? This is the Percent encoding for URIs

Comment: i used the word gibberish because the self.desktop.loadComponentFromURL is returning Unsupported URL.